# Mongoose the Typescript way...?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Trying to implement a Mongoose model in Typescript.  Scouring the Google has revealed only a hybrid approach (combining JS and TS).  How would one go about implementing the User class, on my rather naive approach, without the JS?

Want to be able to IUserModel without the baggage.

```
import {IUser} from './user.ts';
import {Document, Schema, Model} from 'mongoose';

// mixing in a couple of interfaces
interface IUserDocument extends IUser,  Document {}

// mongoose, why oh why '[String]' 
// TODO: investigate out why mongoose needs its own data types
let userSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  userName  : String,
  password  : String,
  firstName : String,
  lastName  : String,
  email     : String,
  activated : Boolean,
  roles     : [String]
});

// interface we want to code to?
export interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {/* any custom methods here */}

// stumped here
export class User {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: `User` can't be a class because creating one is an async operation. It has to return a promise so you have to call `User.create({...}).then...`.

Comment: Specifically, given in the code in the OP, could you please elaborate on why `User` cannot be a class?

Comment: Try https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm instead.

Comment: @Erich they say that typeorm doesn't work well with the MongoDB , maybe Type goose is a good option

Comment: Check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose

Comment: I added a new answer with a 2022 updated version below.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string; 
  somethingElse?: number; 
};

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: true},
  somethingElse: Number,
});

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
export default User;
```

Comment: sorry, but how is 'mongoose' defined in TS?

Comment: `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';` or `import mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Comment: This is solid, thanks!  Can I ask how you're importing and using the model in your app?

Comment: Something like this: `import User from '~/models/user'; User.find(/*...*/).then(/*...*/);`

Comment: How would one define Mongoose object id?

Comment: @Louy when using this `import User from '~/models/user'; `, it looks like it can't determine which export to use. Has somethign changed with TypeScript? To get this to work I have to use: `import User = require('./models/user')` and reference the model with `User.User.find()...`

Comment: `import User ...` can be used with `export default const User`. `import {User} ...` can be used with `export const User`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: How would you add statics with this?

Comment: Don't forget to install the mongoose typings, otherwise many IDEs will not flow with this.

`typings install mongoose`

Comment: Would this work if the IUser interface also needed to work in the browser?  It seems to me The other answer below from Mr. Imre seems like it would work better in this case, but I haven't tried your approach..

Comment: Last line (export default const User...) does not work for me. I need to split the line, as proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821614/typescript-compile-error-error-ts1109-expression-expected

Comment: @Louy If somethingElse property in the interface IUser was not a number but another interface say IRole, whether the IRole interface would also extend mongoose.Document?

Comment: @Aniket if it was a subdocument yes it should extend `Document`, otherwise I don't think so.

Comment: I can do `let newUser = new User({ iAmNotHere: true })` without any errors in the IDE or at compiling. So what is the reason for creating an interface?

Comment: Can you confirm that if you want an instance method to not have an error you must add the instance method and put it in the interface?

Comment: What's the type of the instantiation of the generated "class" from `const User = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);` ? This answer is otherwise incomplete. I.e. `const myUser: ?? = new User({...});`

Comment: The problem with this is that it duplicates every single field between the interface and the schema, which is a [maintenance risk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way/61154023#61154023).

Comment: I see this answer over and over the whole internet, but what I dont like about it is that it is not DRY. Each time you want to add a field it must be done two times.  There's a clear duplication of code with this approach.

Comment: do I get the ide support if I add this interface? I am not getting it after adding the interface like this.

Comment: Please note that extending Document is [discouraged](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#using-extends-document) by mongoose devs.

Comment: Please note that this approach is not recommended by mongoose docs and will be dropped in the next major version. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#using-extends-document

Answer (score 40):

Another alternative if you want to detach your type definitions and the database implementation.

```
import {IUser} from './user.ts';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

type UserType = IUser & mongoose.Document;
const User = mongoose.model<UserType>('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    userName  : String,
    password  : String,
    /* etc */
}));
```

Inspiration from here: https://github.com/Appsilon/styleguide/wiki/mongoose-typescript-models

Comment: Does the `mongoose.Schema` definition here duplicate the fields from `IUser`? Given that `IUser` is defined in a *different file* the [risk that the fields with get out of sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way/61154023#61154023) as the project grows in complexity and number of developers, is quite high.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid argument worth considering. Using component integration tests may help reducing the risks though. And note that there are approaches and architectures where the type declarations and the DB implementations are separated whether it's done via an ORM (as you proposed) or manually (like in this answer). No silver bullet there is... <(°.°)>

Comment: One bullet might be to [generate code](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/3859) from the GraphQL definition, for TypeScript and mongoose.

Comment: For the ones looking for automatic inference of the types:

Assuming UserSchema is already declared and `InferSchemaType` and `Document` imported from Mongoose.
`type UserType = InferSchemaType<typeof UserSchema> & Document`

Answer (score 38):

Most answers here repeat the fields in the TypeScript class/interface, and in the mongoose schema. Not having a single source of truth represents a maintenance risk, as the project becomes more complex and more developers work on it: **fields are more likely to get out of sync**. This is particularly bad when the class is in a different file vs. the mongoose schema.

To keep fields in sync, it makes sense to define them once. There are a few libraries that do this:

- [typeodm.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeodm.io) - full test coverage, good examples, no traction yet
- [mongoose-decorators-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-decorators-ts) - best English, no traction yet
- [typegoose](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/) - most popular, documentation [needs improvement](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/pulls?q=is%3Apr+author%3Adandv)
- [ts-mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mongoose) - doesn't use decorators, second most popular, not actively maintained
- [mongoose-schema-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-schema-decorators) - no traction yet
- [mongoose-typescript](https://github.com/bangbang93/mongoose-typescript/issues/4) - fork of typegoose

I haven't yet been fully convinced by any of them but typegoose seems actively maintained, and the developer accepted my PRs.

To think one step ahead: when you add a GraphQL schema into the mix, another layer of model duplication appears. One way to overcome this problem might be to [generate TypeScript and mongoose code](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/3859) from the GraphQL schema.

Comment: Using Graphql to generate typescript types will be problematic if the entity has additional graphql fields which don't exist in Mongoose schema, because the type will have not just the mongoose schema fields but also the additional fields from graphql.

Answer (score 27):

Sorry for necroposting but this can be still interesting for someone.
I think [Typegoose](https://github.com/szokodiakos/typegoose) provides more modern and elegant way to define models

Here is an example from the docs:

```
import { prop, Typegoose, ModelType, InstanceType } from 'typegoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

class User extends Typegoose {
    @prop()
    name?: string;
}

const UserModel = new User().getModelForClass(User);

// UserModel is a regular Mongoose Model with correct types
(async () => {
    const u = new UserModel({ name: 'JohnDoe' });
    await u.save();
    const user = await UserModel.findOne();

    // prints { _id: 59218f686409d670a97e53e0, name: 'JohnDoe', __v: 0 }
    console.log(user);
})();
```

For an existing connection scenario, you can use as the following (which may be more likely in the real situations and uncovered in the docs):

```
import { prop, Typegoose, ModelType, InstanceType } from 'typegoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

class User extends Typegoose {
    @prop()
    name?: string;
}

// Notice that the collection name will be 'users':
const UserModel = new User().getModelForClass(User, {existingConnection: conn});

// UserModel is a regular Mongoose Model with correct types
(async () => {
    const u = new UserModel({ name: 'JohnDoe' });
    await u.save();
    const user = await UserModel.findOne();

    // prints { _id: 59218f686409d670a97e53e0, name: 'JohnDoe', __v: 0 }
    console.log(user);
})();
```

Comment: I also came to this conclusion, but am worried that `typegoose` doesn't have enough support... checking their npm stats, it's only 3k weekly downloads, and rn there are almost 100 open Github issues, most of which don't have comments, and some of which looks like they should have been closed a long time ago

Comment: @Corbfon Did you try it? If so, what were your findings? If not, was there anything else that made you decide not to use it?

I generally see some people worrying about complete support, but it seems those who actually use it are quite happy with it

Comment: @N4ppeL I wouldn't go with `typegoose` - we ended up manually handling our typing, similar to [this post](https://brianflove.com/2016/10/04/typescript-declaring-mongoose-schema-model/), it looks like `ts-mongoose` might have some promise (as suggested in later answer)

Comment: Never apologize for "necroposting". [As you now know...] There's even a badge (though [it ***is*** named Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) ;^D) for doing just this! Necroposting new information and ideas is encouraged!

Comment: @ruffin: I also really don't understand the stigma against posting new and up-to-date solutions to problems.

Comment: Typegoose is currently being maintained and the maintainer is helpful. It also works fairly well.

Answer (score 17):

Try `ts-mongoose`. It uses conditional types to do the mapping.

```js
import { createSchema, Type, typedModel } from 'ts-mongoose';

const UserSchema = createSchema({
  username: Type.string(),
  email: Type.string(),
});

const User = typedModel('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Disclosure: ts-mongoose seems to be created by sky. Seems to be the slickest solution out there.

Comment: Nice package, [are you still maintaining it](https://github.com/lstkz/ts-mongoose/issues/54)?

Comment: Looks nice but we still need mongoose for other logic in api.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a strong typed way to match a plain model with a mongoose schema. The compiler will ensure the definitions passed to mongoose.Schema matches the interface. Once you have the schema, you can use

**common.ts**

```
export type IsRequired<T> =
  undefined extends T
  ? false
  : true;

export type FieldType<T> =
  T extends number ? typeof Number :
  T extends string ? typeof String :
  Object;

export type Field<T> = {
  type: FieldType<T>,
  required: IsRequired<T>,
  enum?: Array<T>
};

export type ModelDefinition<M> = {
  [P in keyof M]-?:
    M[P] extends Array<infer U> ? Array<Field<U>> :
    Field<M[P]>
};
```

**user.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { ModelDefinition } from "./common";

interface User {
  userName  : string,
  password  : string,
  firstName : string,
  lastName  : string,
  email     : string,
  activated : boolean,
  roles     : Array<string>
}

// The typings above expect the more verbose type definitions,
// but this has the benefit of being able to match required
// and optional fields with the corresponding definition.
// TBD: There may be a way to support both types.
const definition: ModelDefinition<User> = {
  userName  : { type: String, required: true },
  password  : { type: String, required: true },
  firstName : { type: String, required: true },
  lastName  : { type: String, required: true },
  email     : { type: String, required: true },
  activated : { type: Boolean, required: true },
  roles     : [ { type: String, required: true } ]
};

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  definition
);
```

Once you have your schema, you can use methods mentioned in other answers such as

```
const userModel = mongoose.model<User & mongoose.Document>('User', schema);
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer.  None of the other answers actually ensured type compatability between the schema and the type/interface.

Comment: @JamieStrauss: what about [not duplicating the fields in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way#comment108118780_59792239)?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I don't think you understand how types work.

Comment: This answer is so underrated. Needs more upvotes. It's the best solution for ensuring type compatibility between document interface and schema as @JamieS already pointed out. For my use-case, I had to add `default?: any` to the Field type and made required optional.

Comment: @Valkay thanks for reminding me of this gem.  And you're right - this answer is criminally underrated.

Answer (score 8):

### 2023 Update

The new recommended way of typing documents is using a single interface. To type documents in your application, you should use `HydratedDocument`:

```
import { HydratedDocument, model, Schema } from "mongoose";

interface Animal {
    name: string;
}

const animalSchema = new Schema<Animal>({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
});

const AnimalModel = model<Animal>("Animal", animalSchema);

const animal: HydratedDocument<Animal> = AnimalModel.findOne( // ...
```

Mongoose advises against extending document.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html

Answer (score 6):

Just add another way (`@types/mongoose` must be installed with `npm install --save-dev @types/mongoose`)

```
import { IUser } from './user.ts';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface IUserModel extends IUser, mongoose.Document {}

const User = mongoose.model<IUserModel>('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    userName: String,
    password: String,
    // ...
}));
```

And the difference between `interface` and `type`, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37233777/2000548)

This way has a advantage, you can add Mongoose static method typings:

```
interface IUserModel extends IUser, mongoose.Document {
  generateJwt: () => string
}
```

Comment: where did you define `generateJwt`?

Comment: @rels `const User = mongoose.model.... password: String, generateJwt: () => { return someJwt; } }));` basically, `generateJwt` becomes another property of the model.

Comment: Would you just add it as a method in this fashion or would you connect it to the methods property?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as It detaches user definition and user DAL. If you want to switch from mongo to another db provider, you won't have to change user interface.

Comment: @RafaeldelRio: the question was about using mongoose with TypeScript. Switching to another DB is antithetic to this goal. And the problem with separating the schema definition from the `IUser` interface declaration *in a different file* is that the [risk of fields getting out of sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way/61154023#61154023) as the project grows in the number of complexity and developers, is quite high.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how guys at Microsoft do it. [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/003f86e0e9bf387c3f83941ab8491550a1d64905/src/models/User.ts)

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export type UserDocument = mongoose.Document & {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    passwordResetToken: string;
    passwordResetExpires: Date;
...
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: String,
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
...
}, { timestamps: true });

export const User = mongoose.model<UserDocument>("User", userSchema);
```

I recommend to check this excellent starter project out when you add TypeScript to your Node project.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

Comment: That duplicates every single field between mongoose and TypeScript, which creates a maintenance risk as the model becomes more complex. Solutions like `ts-mongoose` and `typegoose` solve that problem, though admittedly with quite a bit of syntactic cruft.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to ensure that your schema satisfies the model type and vice versa , this solution offers better typing than what @bingles suggested:

The common type file:
`ToSchema.ts` (Don't panic! Just copy and paste it)

```js
import { Document, Schema, SchemaType, SchemaTypeOpts } from 'mongoose';

type NonOptionalKeys<T> = { [k in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[k] ? never : k }[keyof T];
type OptionalKeys<T> = Exclude<keyof T, NonOptionalKeys<T>>;
type NoDocument<T> = Exclude<T, keyof Document>;
type ForceNotRequired = Omit<SchemaTypeOpts<any>, 'required'> & { required?: false };
type ForceRequired = Omit<SchemaTypeOpts<any>, 'required'> & { required: SchemaTypeOpts<any>['required'] };

export type ToSchema<T> = Record<NoDocument<NonOptionalKeys<T>>, ForceRequired | Schema | SchemaType> &
   Record<NoDocument<OptionalKeys<T>>, ForceNotRequired | Schema | SchemaType>;
```

and an example model:

```js
import { Document, model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { ToSchema } from './ToSchema';

export interface IUser extends Document {
   name?: string;
   surname?: string;
   email: string;
   birthDate?: Date;
   lastLogin?: Date;
}

const userSchemaDefinition: ToSchema<IUser> = {
   surname: String,
   lastLogin: Date,
   role: String, // Error, 'role' does not exist
   name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }, // Error, name is optional! remove 'required'
   email: String, // Error, property 'required' is missing
   // email: {type: String, required: true}, // correct 
   // Error, 'birthDate' is not defined
};

const userSchema = new Schema(userSchemaDefinition);

export const User = model<IUser>('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: Well, promissing, but no type-checking!  If email is defined `email: string` in the interface but in the schema is defined `email: Number` it does not show any errors =(

Answer (score 4):

I am a fans of Plumier, it has [mongoose helper](https://github.com/plumier/plumier/tree/master/packages/mongoose), **but it can be used standalone without Plumier itself**. Unlike Typegoose its took different path by using Plumier's dedicated reflection library, that make it possible to use cools stuff.

#### Features

1. Pure POJO (domain doesn't need to inherit from any class, nor using any special data type), Model created automatically inferred as `T & Document` thus its possible to access document related properties.
2. Supported TypeScript parameter properties, it's good when you have `strict:true` tsconfig configuration. And with parameter properties doesn't require decorator on all properties.
3. Supported field properties like Typegoose
4. Configuration is the same as mongoose so you will get easily familiar with it.
5. Supported inheritance that's make the programming more natural.
6. Model analysis, showing model names and its appropriate collection name, configuration applied etc.

### Usage

```js
import model, {collection} from "@plumier/mongoose"


@collection({ timestamps: true, toJson: { virtuals: true } })
class Domain {
    constructor(
        public createdAt?: Date,
        public updatedAt?: Date,
        @collection.property({ default: false })
        public deleted?: boolean
    ) { }
}

@collection()
class User extends Domain {
    constructor(
        @collection.property({ unique: true })
        public email: string,
        public password: string,
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public dateOfBirth: string,
        public gender: string
    ) { super() }
}

// create mongoose model (can be called multiple time)
const UserModel = model(User)
const user = await UserModel.findById()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example from Mongoose documentation, [Creating from ES6 Classes Using loadClass()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/advanced_schemas.html), converted to TypeScript:

```js
import { Document, Schema, Model, model } from 'mongoose';
import * as assert from 'assert';

const schema = new Schema<IPerson>({ firstName: String, lastName: String });

export interface IPerson extends Document {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  fullName: string;
}

class PersonClass extends Model {
  firstName!: string;
  lastName!: string;

  // `fullName` becomes a virtual
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  set fullName(v) {
    const firstSpace = v.indexOf(' ');
    this.firstName = v.split(' ')[0];
    this.lastName = firstSpace === -1 ? '' : v.substr(firstSpace + 1);
  }

  // `getFullName()` becomes a document method
  getFullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  // `findByFullName()` becomes a static
  static findByFullName(name: string) {
    const firstSpace = name.indexOf(' ');
    const firstName = name.split(' ')[0];
    const lastName = firstSpace === -1 ? '' : name.substr(firstSpace + 1);
    return this.findOne({ firstName, lastName });
  }
}

schema.loadClass(PersonClass);
const Person = model<IPerson>('Person', schema);

(async () => {
  let doc = await Person.create({ firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Snow' });
  assert.equal(doc.fullName, 'Jon Snow');
  doc.fullName = 'Jon Stark';
  assert.equal(doc.firstName, 'Jon');
  assert.equal(doc.lastName, 'Stark');

  doc = (<any>Person).findByFullName('Jon Snow');
  assert.equal(doc.fullName, 'Jon Snow');
})();
```

For the static `findByFullName` method, I couldn't figure how get the type information `Person`, so I had to cast `<any>Person` when I want to call it. If you know how to fix that please add a comment.

Comment: Like [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way#comment108118805_53789111), this approach duplicates the fields between the interface and the schema. That could be avoided by having a single source of truth, e.g. by using `ts-mongoose` or `typegoose`. The situation gets further duplicated when defining the GraphQL schema.

Comment: Any way to define refs with this approach?

Comment: Should be `class PersonModel extends Model<IPerson> {...}`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a solution for existing Mongoose projects:

We recently built [mongoose-tsgen](https://github.com/francescov1/mongoose-tsgen) to address this issue (would love some feedback!). Existing solutions like typegoose required rewriting our entire schemas and introduced various incompatibilities. [mongoose-tsgen](https://github.com/francescov1/mongoose-tsgen) is a simple CLI tool which generates an index.d.ts file containing Typescript interfaces for all your Mongoose schemas; it requires little to no configuration and integrates very smoothly with any Typescript project.

Answer (score 3):

## v6.9 update

You don't need to create a type or an interface no more. You only need a schema to generate the corresponding types:

```
import { model, Schema, HydratedDocumentFromSchema, InferSchemaType } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  somethingElse: Number
});

// Already typed
export const UserModel = model('User', UserSchema);

// Type of an hydrated document (with all the getters, etc...)
export type THydratedUserModel = HydratedDocumentFromSchema<typeof UserSchema>;

// Only the fields defined in the shema
export type TUserModel = InferSchemaType<typeof UserSchema>;
```

⚠️ As of writing this, these type helpers (`HydratedDocumentFromSchema` and `InferSchemaType`) are undocumented.

Comment: Cool! But I wonder why `export interface TUserModel = InferSchemaType<typeof UserSchema>;` doesn't work as well ...

Answer (score 2):

### With this <kbd>vscode intellisense</kbd> works on both

- **User Type** *User.findOne*
- **user instance** *u1._id*

---

### The Code:

```js
// imports
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb'
import { Document, model, Schema, SchemaDefinition } from 'mongoose'

import { authSchema, IAuthSchema } from './userAuth'

// the model

export interface IUser {
  _id: ObjectID, // !WARNING: No default value in Schema
  auth: IAuthSchema
}

// IUser will act like it is a Schema, it is more common to use this
// For example you can use this type at passport.serialize
export type IUserSchema = IUser & SchemaDefinition
// IUser will act like it is a Document
export type IUserDocument = IUser & Document

export const userSchema = new Schema<IUserSchema>({
  auth: {
    required: true,
    type: authSchema,
  }
})

export default model<IUserDocument>('user', userSchema)
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the following approach the easiest and most efficient since it validates the keys in the schema with the extra interface you define, helping you keep everything in sync.

You also get the amazing typescript autocomplete suggestions when you are adding/changing schema validator properties like maxlength, lowercase, etc on the schema.

Win win!

```
import { Document, model, Schema, SchemaDefinitionProperty } from "mongoose";

type TDocument<Fields> = Fields & Document;
type TSchema<Fields> = Record<keyof Fields, SchemaDefinitionProperty>;

type UserFields = {
  email: string;
  firstName?: string;
  roles?: string[];
};

const userSchema: TSchema<UserFields> = {
  email: { type: Schema.Types.String, required: true, index: true },
  firstName: { type: Schema.Types.String, maxlength: 30, trim: true },
  roles: [
    { type: Schema.Types.String, maxlength: 20, lowercase: true },
  ],
};

export const User = model<TDocument<UserFields>>(
  "User",
  new Schema(userSchema, { timestamps: true })
);
```

Best part! you could reuse TDocument and TSchema types for all your models.

Answer (score 2):

Official documents discourage TS interface to extend Document.

> This approach works, but we recommend your document interface not extend Document. Using extends Document makes it difficult for Mongoose to infer which properties are present on query filters, lean documents, and other cases.

**TS Interface**

```
export interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  fullName: string;
}
```

**Schema**

```
    const personSchema = new Schema<IPerson>({
      //You get intellisense of properties so less error prone
      firstName:{type:String},
      lastName:{type:String}
    })

   personSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function(this:IPerson) {
    return this.firstName + " " this.lastName
   });

   export const User = model<IPerson>('person',personSchema)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose introduced officially supported TypeScript bindings in v5.11.0.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html describes Mongoose's recommended approach to working with Mongoose in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

[As per mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#using-extends-document)

> Alternatively, your document interface can extend Mongoose's Document
> class.
>
> We strongly recommend against using this approach, its support will be
> dropped in the next major version as it causes major performance
> issues.

Instead you can use *HydratedDocument*

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  phone: string;
  address: string[];
  orders: ObjectId[];
}
export type UserDoc = HydratedDocument<User>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based off the README for the [`@types/mongoose`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mongoose) package.

Besides the elements already included above it shows how to include regular and static methods:

```
import { Document, model, Model, Schema } from "mongoose";

interface IUserDocument extends Document {
  name: string;
  method1: () => string;
}
interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {
  static1: () => string;
}

var UserSchema = new Schema<IUserDocument & IUserModel>({
  name: String
});

UserSchema.methods.method1 = function() {
  return this.name;
};
UserSchema.statics.static1 = function() {
  return "";
};

var UserModel: IUserModel = model<IUserDocument, IUserModel>(
  "User",
  UserSchema
);
UserModel.static1(); // static methods are available

var user = new UserModel({ name: "Success" });
user.method1();
```

In general, this README appears to be a fantastic resource for approaching types with mongoose.

Comment: This approach duplicates the definition of every field from `IUserDocument` into `UserSchema`, which creates a maintenance risk as the model becomes more complex. Packages like `ts-mongoose` and `typegoose` attempt to solve that problem, though admittedly with quite a bit of syntactic cruft.

Answer (score 0):

The latest mongoose package has come with typescript support. You don't need to use @types/mongoose anymore.  See my example here.

https://jasonching2005.medium.com/complete-guide-for-using-typescript-in-mongoose-with-lean-function-e55adf1189dc

Comment: How to see when i must to pay to see.

Comment: open in incognito mode. hehe

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the following link really really helpful where the author has described each and every step in details without using any library.

[Typescript With MongoDB and Node/Express](https://medium.com/swlh/typescript-with-mongoose-and-node-express-24073d51d2ee)

This has really really helped me and hoping will be very helpful for those searching for a solution without installing any extra plugin.

However, if you like you can give a try to [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/) and [TypeGoose](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/)

But I prefer to go without installing any library :-).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is what you are looking for
but there's a package called [Typegoose](https://typegoose.github.io/)

Comment: Typegoose is already mentioned in several previous answers; this provides no new information whatsoever.