# Typescript compile error: error TS1109: Expression expected

Tags: typescript

I have this very simple typescript file:

```
export default const VERSION: number = 2016030600;
```

Then I run:

```
tsc version.ts
```

typescript compiler (Version 1.8.7, OS X) complains:

```
version.ts(1,16): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

How can I fix this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do your `VERSION` assignment as a separate statement:

```
const VERSION: number = 2016030600;
export default VERSION;
```

Comment: Quick/related note: if you find this same error in a declaration file, this answer hinted to me the correct syntax there which is `declare const VERSION: number; export default VERSION`.

Comment: It would be interesting to know ***why*** we need to use separate statements as well.