# "ts 1109" with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to put my code but I have 1 wrong answer with if statement.

My error code is ts1109 and I don't no why VS code put that.

Thank you for helping me :)

```
var calculator = new Vue ({
    el:'#calculator',
    data: {
        price:'',
        purcentage: '',
        minimum: '',
        maximum: '',
        calcPayment: ''
    },
    computed: {
        calcPayment: function(e){
            var p= this.price / 100 * this.purcentage;
            var r= if (p < this.minimum) {
                return this.minimum
            } else if (p > this.maxiumum) {
                return this.maximum
            } else {
                return p
            };
            
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript compile error: error TS1109: Expression expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821614/typescript-compile-error-error-ts1109-expression-expected)

Answer (score 1):

```
var r = if (/*etc*/
```

It's pointing out that you can't have an `if` statement on the right hand side of an assignment