# In React How to pass object using history.push from a component to child component and read data

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have parent component which showing records in table. When user click it redirect to child component with record Id passing in parameter using history push. This is all working fine but I need to pass an object of data in addition to parameter which I am not able to achieve and also what steps I need in child component to read this object?

### Object Definition

```
export interface ISearchCriteriaForm{
  startTime: string,
  endTime: string,
  liveTime?: string,
  schedAction_Active: string,
  siteId?: number,
  scheduleId?: number
}
```

### Parent Component

```
const MyComponentA = () => {

 const [url] = useState("/eziTracker/eziStatus");
const[eziSearchCriteria, setEziSearchCriteria] = useState<ISearchCriteriaForm>();

//when row clicked on table
const selectedRow = (row: any) => { 
//history.push(`${url}/${row.siteId}`);  // this works
 
 history.push({     // this is how I am trying to achieve ??
   pathname: `${url}/${row.siteId}`,
   state: eziStatusSearchCriteria
  });
 };
```

### Child Component

```
const MyChildComponent = () =>{
  const match = useRouteMatch("/eziTracker/eziStatus/:id/:hash");
  const[eziStatusSearchCriteria, setEziStatusSearchCriteria] = useState<IEziStatusSearchCriteriaForm>();

  useEffect(() =>{
  
  },[]);
```

### error

```
Expression expected.  TS1109

   88 |       pathname: `${url}/${row.siteId}`,
   89 |       state: eziStatusSearchCriteria
 > 90 |     });
      |     ^
   91 | };
   92 | 
   93 | const setDefaultSearchCriteria = () =>{
```

Comment: I think this is not an issue in typescript issue instead of rect.js  error. I think you should assign `{     // this is how I am trying to achieve ??
   pathname: `${url}/${row.siteId}`,
   state: eziStatusSearchCriteria
  }` state to variable and call it again in the history.push method as 2 statements. like, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821614/typescript-compile-error-error-ts1109-expression-expected

Comment: Do you want filter table data using the query parameter?

Comment: You are right, I have change the way I assign value to state and it did work, refer to my asnswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you need to do something like this to achieve you're goal:

first you need to create a `location object` for `history.push` function like this:

```
const location = {
   pathname: `${url}/${row.siteId}`,
   state: eziStatusSearchCriteria || {}
}
```

and then use `history.push(location)` to go to your specified `location` and then in the destination all you need to do is to some how access `location` object which the easiest way is to use `useLocation` hook like this:

```
const location = useLocation();

//NOW you can use location.state object to get your data
```

Comment: @Toxic Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Parent component

```
const selectedRow = (row: any) => { 

eziSearchCriteria.siteId = row.siteId;

history.push({
  pathname: `${url}/${row.siteId}`,
  state: {searchCriteria: eziSearchCriteria}
});
};
```

### Child Component

```
  let location = useLocation();

  const setSearchCriteria =() =>{
   if(location.state.searchCriteria!=null || location.state.searchCriteria !=''){
     setEziStatusSearchCriteria(location.state.searchCriteria)
   }
 }
```