# Cannot extend base class with Mongoose and Typescript in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm attempting to use Mongoose 4.5.4 and [it's typings](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7e4710a23ce3779826c4d26d1cf637851924a299/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts) in NodeJS with Typescript (obviously) while utilizing the Repository Pattern.

RepositoryBase:

```
export class RepositoryBase<T extends mongoose.Document> implements IRead<T>, IWrite<T> {
    private _model: mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>;

    constructor(schemaModel: mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>) {
        this._model = schemaModel;
    }

    create(item: T): mongoose.Promise<mongoose.model<T>> {
        return this._model.create(item);
    }

    //......
    //Additional CRUD methods excluded for brevity
}
```

UserRepository:

```
export class UserRepository extends RepositoryBase<IUserModel> {
    constructor() {
        super(UserSchema);
    }
}
```

I have the following type error on the call to `super()` from `UserRepository`

`[ts] 
Argument of type '<U>(name: string) => IModelConstructor<U> & EventEmitter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IModelConstructor<Document> & EventEmitter'.
  Type '<U>(name: string) => IModelConstructor<U> & EventEmitter' is not assignable to type 'IModelConstructor<Document>'.
    Property 'findById' is missing in type '<U>(name: string) => IModelConstructor<U> & EventEmitter'.
import UserSchema`

Does anyone know why? My creation of my model (`UserSchema`) is very simple:
`let model = mongooseConnection.model<IUserModel>("Users", UserSchema.schema);`

I would much appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: See 2 solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way (Disclaimer: one of them is mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a simple `export const model = mongooseConnection.model<IUserModel>("Users", UserSchema.schema);` was enough to solve this typing issue.