# Static methods with typescript & mongoose does: "An interface may only extend a class or another interface."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I try to add a static method to my Model, but if I do it, I got this Error: `An interface may only extend a class or another interface.`

This is my code:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {IPermission} from './IPermission';

export interface IRoleDocument extends mongoose.Document {
    name: string,
    inherit_from: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Role'
    },
    permissions: Array<IPermission>
};

export interface IRole extends mongoose.Model<IRoleDocument> {

};
```

Error comes from `export interface IRole extends mongoose.Model<IRoleDocument>`

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

As far I I know it is impossible to inherit from intersection/union types in typescript. And in case of mongoose type definitions `mongoose.Model<T>` is declared as intersection type:

```
type ModelConstructor<T> = IModelConstructor<T> & events.EventEmitter;
```

For examples of how to use mongoose in typescript you can check this [topic on SA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way)

But you still can use intersection instead of inheritance to get your required interface, like this:

```
interface IRoleDefinition
{
    myExtraProperty: string;
}

type IRole = mongoose.Model<IRoleDocument> & IRoleDefinition;
```

More info about intersection types vs inheritance: [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4278)

Comment: I read the thread of SA. But there is no declaration for static methods. If I did it on your example the IRoleDefinition defines are found but not static. And the member in IRoleDocument doesn't exists for TypeScript.

Comment: I am not an expert in mongoose. To help you I would like to clarify the following points: 1) Interface cannot have both static and instance methods declared at the same time - two separate interfaces are usually used 2) it is impossible to extend mongoose.Model<T> as it is intersection type.

Comment: I googled how to create static methods that typescript find and the way I write was the answer... maybe a depracted way. I know that Interfaces only can have one of the method types but how to tell typescript which I mean?  To the second point, im not clearly sure...