# Mongoose loadClass issue with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm taking advantage of mongoose [class schemas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/advanced_schemas.html).

And using TypeScript for my Node project.

I've followed [Mongoose the Typescript way...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way) to make sure my Model is aware of the schema I've defined, So I've auto-completion etc..

However it becomes more tricky with schema class.
As written in their docs:

> The loadClass() function lets you pull in methods, statics, and
>   virtuals from an ES6 class. A class method maps to a schema method, a
>   static method maps to a schema static, and getters/setters map to
>   virtuals.

So my code looks something like:

```js
interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type:String, required: true},
  lastName: {type:String, required: true},
});

class UserClass{
   static allUsersStartingWithLetter(letter: string){
       return this.find({...});
   }
   fullName(this: IUser){
      return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
   }
}
userSchema.loadClass(UserClass);

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema);
export default User;
```

My goal is that TypeScript will understand that:

1. `User` has a method `allUsersStartingWithLetter`
2. `User` instance has a method `fullName`

In the current configuration it does not.
I was not able to accomplish it myself.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are creating new models for example?
You cannot use model.create(your props), you have to use new User().save(). If you do that, it is working. (I had the same issue)

Answer (score 0):

Do you **really** need to use classes? You could accomplish this using interfaces without using classes to do it. Here's an example:

```
/* eslint-disable func-names */
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
export interface Foo {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

export type FooDocument = mongoose.Document & Foo;

const fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

fooSchema.methods.bar = function (): void {
  const foo = this as FooDocument;
  foo.name = 'bar';
};

const FooModel = mongoose.model<FooDocument>('foos', fooSchema);

export default FooModel;
```

This way you can use the `Foo` interface for methods with the inversion depedency. Them in your repository will return `Foo` instead of FooDocument...

Extra: If you use `lean()` in your database requests you return exactly the `Foo` interface. [More information for lean here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding `extends mongoose.Model` to the `UserClass`?

```
class UserClass extends mongoose.Model<IUser> {
   static allUsersStartingWithLetter(letter: string){
       return this.find({...});
   }
   fullName(this: IUser){
      return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `UserClass` needs to extend `Model` from `mongoose`. You seem to be missing a bit of required code to make this work for you.

From the link you shared as a reference, here's a guide that should solve your issue with complete code example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58107396/1919397

Comment: No, it is not required to extend from document. See documentation:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/advanced_schemas.html

It should work without extending from Document.