# Return object from database without type functions/methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

In the object store there is functions declared. I would like that method returns the properties values fill and it methods declarations. Is there this possibility ?

```
export async function findOne(conditions: any, projection: any = {}): Promise<store> {
    return await Store.findOne(conditions, projection);
}
```

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34482136/457268

Comment: Can you please explicate your expected result and what you are currently getting?