# Strongly typed models with Mongoose and NestJS

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

As far as NestJS has a proper way of define a Model using
`MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Cat', schema: CatSchema }], 'cats')`

How can we defined strongly typed models ?!

Just as we do on regular typescript ([Mongoose the Typescript way...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way))

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use typegoose for nest js [nest/typegoose](https://github.com/kpfromer/nestjs-typegoose)

Comment: I have tried that, but even doing everything my models still of type any :/ It only reduces to me the necessity to create a objeto for the schema using annotations

Comment: you just  @InjectModel it can make the job