# How can I use MongooseArray.prototype.pull() with typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Typescript is complaining at this line:

```
user.posts.pull(postId);
```

I am getting this error:

```
     Property 'pull' does not exist on type 'PostDoc[]'
```

since postId is received as `req.params.postId` it is type string, so i converted it to mongoose objectId but i still have the same error:

```
  user.posts.pull(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId));
```

pull() works in mongoose arrays. this line of code how I implemented in javacsript. I am converting my project to typescript. this is the user interface and schema for user model.

```
interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  posts: PostDoc[];
  name: string;
  status: string;
}
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  status: { type: String, default: "I am a new user" },
  posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
});
```

Here post schema and interface

```
interface PostDoc extends Document {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  creator: Types.ObjectId;
}
const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    creator: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
```

Comment: If you see the error message, `Property 'pull' does not exist on type 'PostDoc[]'`, it tells you everything you need to know

Comment: @KunalMukherjee same line of code works in javascript. just switching to typescript, does not mean that, they discarded pull method?

Comment: Please add your post schema in the question, does it extend `mongoose.Document` ?

Comment: Also try adding the npm package as a dev dependency - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose

Comment: @KunalMukherjee i did and also @types/mongoose is installed as dev dependency

Comment: In the interface `PostDoc` the `Document` refers to `mongoose.Document` right, have you destructured it on the top ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced a similar problem to properly type the subdocuments. I propose you the following solution in order to keep both the DTO interface and the model interface separated and strongly typed. The same would apply for your `PostDoc`.

#### UserDoc DTO

```
interface UserDoc {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  posts: PostDoc[];
  name: string;
  status: string;
}
```

#### UserDoc Model

```
export type UserDocModel = UserDoc & mongoose.Document & PostDocModel & Omit<UserDoc , 'posts'>

interface PostDocModel {
  posts: mongoose.Types.Array<PostModel>;
};
```

We replace the `posts: PostDoc[]` property with [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) for our *mongoose array* of `PostModel`, maintaining the properties synchronized. Inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36661990

In this way we could access every mongoose array method such as `pull`, `pop`, `shift`, etc. (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Array)

```
const user = await this.userdocModel.findById(userId).exec();
user.posts.pull(postId);
```

#### Exporting the model

```
const User = mongoose.model<UserDocModel>('User', userSchema);
export default User;
```

Comment: This is very helpful information. I learnt alot. one thing, how did u initialize this.userdocModel. I used like this "await UserDocModel.findById(req.userId)" but did not work

Comment: I just realize that UserDocModel is just type so cannot be used instead of User

Comment: @Yilmaz in my case i am using NestJS (docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb) (a Node.js framework), to inject and initialize the model. However I think you should be able to export the model and use it like this: const User = mongoose.model<UserDocModel>('User', userSchema); export User;