# Typescript - Function return type if I want to return object

Tags: node.js, typescript

Note: Please read through before answering. It looks like a simple question but I'm not sure if it is that simple. Plus I'm new to typescript so go easy on me :p

So here is the use case. I have a model user and I wrote a generic function to check if the user exist based on the email in the DB or not. If it exist it returns the user object.

Now if it would have been any other object then I could have defined the type and carry on with my code but it's the user object I'm getting from DB, not sure how to solve this problem.

I have found the work around for it by mentioning the return type "any" but my soul is not at peace with it. This feels more like a hack than a solution.

Enough talking, here's the code:

```
export const existingUser = async (email: string): Promise<any> => {
  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  return foundUser;
};
```

Now as I mentioned above this works, but I tried one different way which was throwing error. I have defined my user model types shown below:

```
export interface Iuser extends Document {
  profile_picture_url?: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  phone_number?: string;
  is_agree_terms_at: string;
  gender?: Gender;
  role: UserRole;
  isValid: boolean;
}
```

and then mentioned the Iuser as my return type because that's the type of object I was expecting from the DB. I know it will have other fields once it is added in DB but I don't know any better -_-

```
export const existingUser = async (email: string): Promise<Iuser> => {
  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  return foundUser;
};
```

Please help me out. I'm not able to sleep.

Comment: Can you update the error ? Also, please update the document interface as you extending that and how your schema looks for User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem- Your function is `async`, it returns a promise, so you need to wrap `Iuser` inside a promise type-

```
// NOTE: This code doesn't work just yet, there are more issues
export const existingUser = async (email: string): Promise<Iuser> => {
  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  return foundUser;
};
```

Second and main problem - If you check the return type of [`.findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) - you'll notice it returns a union type - Either the document that it found **or** `null` (in case your query does not match anything).

This means the type of `foundUser` is really, `Iuser | null`, but you're treating it as `Iuser` - which is not compatible.

What you can do instead is-

```
export const existingUser = async (email: string): Promise<Iuser | null> => {
  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  return foundUser;
};
```

Which will also return either `Iuser | null`.

Or if you're **100% certain** the user must exist-

```
export const existingUser = async (email: string): Promise<Iuser> => {
  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  return foundUser!;
};
```

The [`!` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) asserts the type is **not null**.

Or, if you'd like throw an exception when the user is not found-

```
export const existingUser = async (email: string): Promise<Iuser> => {
  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  if (!foundUser) {
      throw new Error('User not found');
  }
  return foundUser;
};
```

Check out [using mongoose with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way) to get a general understanding about how to bake your `Iuser` type directly into your mongoose model - which will let the type system do all the type inferring work for you in this case.

Comment: my bad on not mentioning promise in the return type. I have updated the question. And thanks for the answer it totally makes sense. 

cheers